# Python 3: get subtotal from a list (dictionaries) by key variable

Tags: python

I am a Python 3 beginner and I am trying to practice some examples.
I have dictionary data (year, month) formatted as follows:

```
year month yearmonth x1 x2 x3 ...
1999  1     199901   10 20 30 ...
1999  3     199903   10 20 30 ...
2000  4     200004   10 20 30 ...
2000  9     200009   10 20 30 ...
2000  10    200010   10 20 30 ...
.................................
.................................
```

I would like to get subtotals for each year for certain keys, e.g. subtotal for only variable `x2`. The expected result is to return the following:

```
year  totalx2 
1999     40
2000     60
.........
```

Of course, in my data there are more years and months than presented here. If there is a missing month for a certain year, I will assume that the value is 0 when adding the 12 months subtotal.

Any help would be great! Thanks for your patient with a beginner.
Joe

Comment: How is your dictionary structured, can you provide some code?

Comment: Can you give more details about how your dict looks like?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using the pandas library to do this.  A similar answer was stated here:

[Pandas sum by groupby, but exclude certain columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751229/pandas-sum-by-groupby-but-exclude-certain-columns)

Answer (score 0):

you could try grouping values by year in new dict, that would make them easy to manipulate with, and then do your thing. it would look something like this

`from collections import defaultdict`

`def group_by_year(list, key):
    total = "total_" + key
    new_dict = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
    for row in list:
        year = row["year"]
        if not new_dict[year]:
            new_dict[year] = {"year": year, total: row[key]}
        else:
            new_dict[year][total] += row[key]
    return [new_dict[key] for key in new_dict]`