# how to check and groupby all the objects starts with of a dataframe in column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have a dataframe where I need to check , group by and sum all the data

I have used regex function to find and group all the particular group of data starts with respective countries.

Suppose I have a dataset

```
Countries    31-12-17   1-1-18  2-1-18  3-1-18  Sum
India-Basic    1200      1100    800     900    4000
Sweden-Basic   1500      1300    700     1500   5000
Norway-Basic   800       400     900      900   3000
India-Exp      600       1400    300      200   2500
Sweden-Exp     1800      400     600     700    3500
Norway-Exp     1300      1600    1100    1500   4500
```

Expected Output :

```
Countries    Sum
India        6500
Sweden       8500
Norway       7500
```

India

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas sum by groupby, but exclude certain columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751229/pandas-sum-by-groupby-but-exclude-certain-columns)

Answer (score 3):

Use for regex solution [`Series.str.extract`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) and aggregate `sum`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(df['Countries'].str.extract('(.*)-', expand=False), sort=False)['Sum']
         .sum()
         .reset_index())
print (df1)
  Countries   Sum
0     India  6500
1    Sweden  8500
2    Norway  7500
```

Alternative si split `Countries` by `-` and select first lists by `str[0]`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(df['Countries'].str.split('-').str[0], sort=False)['Sum']
        .sum()
        .reset_index())
print (df1)
  Countries   Sum
0     India  6500
1    Sweden  8500
2    Norway  7500
```

Comment: Downvoter, if there's something wrong with my answer, please let me know, so I can correct it. Thanks.

Comment: how to sum the data from 2-1-18 (date) column onwards . ?

Comment: @neeraj04 - Do you think  how create last `Sum` column? It means there is no `Sum` column? Then use `df['Sum'] = df.loc[:, '2-1-18':].sum(axis=1)`

Comment: df['Sum'] = df.loc[:, '2-1-18':].sum(axis=1) is not working , its giving unexceptional value

Comment: @neeraj04 - So need `df['Sum'] = df.loc[:, '2-1-18':].drop('Sum', axis=1).sum(axis=1)` ? Because `Sum` column already exist?

Comment: I have created an separate column with  the column name "sumval" and the row data contains some null values as well .

Comment: @neeraj04 - not sure if understand. What is `giving unexceptional value` ? sum use some more columns? Or some error?

Comment: When I am finding the sum in the excel by manually selecting the required row  its giving different value but when finding it with the above statement its giving different value

Comment: @neeraj04 - What is difference? there is count some column which has to be excluded? I have no real data, so is necessary be detective here ;)

Answer (score 1):

this could work - note that i only filtered for the columns that are relevant :

```
(df.filter(['Countries','Sum'])
 .assign(Countries = lambda x: x.Countries.str.split('-').str.get(0))
 .groupby('Countries')
 .agg('sum')
)    


             Sum
Countries   
 India      6500
 Norway     7500
 Sweden     8500
```