# Groupby in pandas by including the columns which are in group by condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

using the example from [Pandas sum by groupby, but exclude certain columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32751229/pandas-sum-by-groupby-but-exclude-certain-columns)

```
Code   Country      Item_Code   Item    Ele_Code    Unit    Y1961    Y1962   Y1963
2      Afghanistan  15          Wheat   5312        Ha      10       20      30
2      Afghanistan  25          Maize   5312        Ha      10       20      30
4      Angola       15          Wheat   7312        Ha      30       40      50
4      Angola       25          Maize   7312        Ha      30       40      50
```

when we do the

```
df.groupby(['Country', 'Item_Code'])[["Y1961", "Y1962", "Y1963"]].sum()
```

the output will be

```
                       Y1961  Y1962  Y1963
Country     Item_Code
Afghanistan 15            10     20     30
            25            10     20     30
Angola      15            30     40     50
            25            30     40     50
```

Now , here is my questions

when I do `df.columns` i will only get `Y1961  Y1962  Y1963`

But what if I want `Country, Item_Code` are included as columns like below

```
df.columns

Country, Item_Code ,Y1961  Y1962  Y1963
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to specify the arg `as_index=False`

```
df.groupby(['Country', 'Item_Code'],as_index=False)[["Y1961", "Y1962", "Y1963"]].sum()


       Country  Item_Code  Y1961  Y1962  Y1963
0  Afghanistan         15     10     20     30
1  Afghanistan         25     10     20     30
2       Angola         15     30     40     50
3       Angola         25     30     40     50


df.columns

Index(['Code', 'Country', 'Item_Code', 'Item', 'Ele_Code', 'Unit', 'Y1961',
       'Y1962', 'Y1963'],
      dtype='object')
```

you could also do

```
df.groupby(['Country', 'Item_Code'])[["Y1961", "Y1962", "Y1963"]].sum().reset_index()
```

Comment: It worked ! also I have used Dishin H Goyani code for combining them .

Answer (score 1):

Those are now index names. You can get that using `df.index.names`.

```
list(df.index.names) + df.columns.to_list()
['Country', 'Item_Code', 'Y1961', 'Y1962', 'Y1963']
```