# Alternative ways to summarize dataframe feature (nested for loops, groupby)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, group-by

The dataframe below represents one month's worth of customer presence with a one hour granularity. Time of presence is documented as two columns `"REGIS_DAY"` and `"REGIS_HOUR"`. `"REGIS_DAY"` is day of month and `"REGIS_HOUR"` is hours of day.

```
REGIS_DAY REGIS_HOUR  REGIS_DATE     REGIS_TIME
7             16       7/10/2011     16:21:05
3             3        3/10/2011     3:57:45
16            4        16/10/2011    4:08:47
24            3        24/10/2011    3:09:47
29            13       29/10/2011    13:43:40
7             16       7/10/2011     16:41:05
3             3        3/10/2011     3:24:45
3             3        3/10/2011     3:24:00
29            13       29/10/2011    13:43:01
29            13       29/10/2011    13:10:40
29            13       29/10/2011    13:20:40
```

**Input data:** (`df.to_dict()`)

```
{'REGIS_DAY': {0: '7', 1: '3', 2: '16', 3: '24', 4: '29', 5: '7', 6: '3', 7: '3', 8: '29', 9: '29', 10: '29'}, 
 'REGIS_HOUR': {0: '16', 1: '3', 2: '4', 3: '3', 4: '13', 5: '16', 6: '3', 7: '3', 8: '13', 9: '13', 10: '13'}, 
 'REGIS_DATE': {0: '7/10/2011', 1: '3/10/2011', 2: '16/10/2011', 3: '24/10/2011', 4: '29/10/2011', 5: '7/10/2011', 6: '3/10/2011', 7: '3/10/2011', 8: '29/10/2011', 9: '29/10/2011', 10: '29/10/2011'}, 
 'REGIS_TIME': {0: '16:21:05', 1: '3:57:45', 2: '4:08:47', 3: '3:09:47', 4: '13:43:40', 5: '16:41:05', 6: '3:24:45', 7: '3:24:00', 8: '13:43:01', 9: '13:10:40', 10: '13:20:40'}}
```

In this assignment, I am required to calculate the number of customers present at the same time every hour by way of `for` loops. So I iterate over every day (that is 31) and every 24 hours:

```
data_3124 = np.zeros((31,24), dtype = float)
for i in range(31):
    for j in range(24):
        number = (df.REGIS_DAY == (i+1)) & (df.REGIS_HOUR == j)
        data_3124[i,j] = number.sum()
```

**Problem:** The code above returns 0 for all values.

**Expected output**:

```
REGIS_DAY   REGIS_HOUR    sum
7             16           2
3             3            3
29            13           4
16            4            1
24            3            1
```

This reads like at day 7 and hour 16, the total number of customers present at the same time was 2; similarly for day 3 and hour 3, there were 3 customers.

I have also tried the `.isin` function. I understand my way of finding the solution is wrong.

---

**Additional information**

***OCa's*** and  ***Kirill Kondratenko's*** solution without loop

```
 df_result = (df_2011
      .groupby(['REGIS_DAY', 'REGIS_HOUR'])
      .size()
      .reset_index()
      .rename(columns={0:'sum'}))
```

and

```
df1 = df_2011.groupby(by=['REGIS_DAY','REGIS_HOUR'], as_index=False).size()
```

do yield below expected/correct result. Why is it then, that my nested loops method always sum 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1. Setting data types right

You are applying numerical methods to data that contains only strings. That is why your attempts return empty tables. Integer `1` will not match string `'1'`. While some methods won't care the data type (see `groupby` method below), your nested loops on the numpy array do require actual numbers. Hence you must start with this datatype conversion:

```py
df[['REGIS_DAY','REGIS_HOUR']] = df[['REGIS_DAY','REGIS_HOUR']].astype('int')

df.dtypes

REGIS_DAY      int32
REGIS_HOUR     int32
REGIS_DATE    object
REGIS_TIME    object
dtype: object
```

Now you can work.
For more on the subject, see e.g. [Change column type in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15891038/12846804)

---

#### 2. About your first attempt

Your code snippet was correctly written and returns the expected 31*24 array. It just does not look like the most convenient way to gather the data so that you may further use them.

```py
# This was fine all along:
data_3124 = np.zeros((31,24), dtype = float)
for i in range(31):
    for j in range(24):
        number = (df.REGIS_DAY == (i+1)) & (df.REGIS_HOUR == j)
        data_3124[i,j] = number.sum()
```

You may probe it with a couple checks:

```
data_3124.sum()
11
# This is indeed the number of rows in the initial dataframe

data_3124[6,16]
2.0
# Number of hits for day 7, hour 16.
```

---

#### 3. The pythonic way to do it

Now it takes one line with `groupby` to define another dataframe just like you need it: (conversion from string to integer not required for that one to work)

```py
df1 = df.groupby(by=['REGIS_DAY','REGIS_HOUR'], as_index=False).size()

   REGIS_DAY  REGIS_HOUR  size
0          3           3     3
1          7          16     2
2         16           4     1
3         24           3     1
4         29          13     4
```

If you still would like to solve this with loops, we can look into that too, but know that this here will be the recommended method.
For further reading, you may try: [Pandas sum by groupby, but exclude certain columns](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32751229/12846804)

---

#### 4. A suggestion with nested loops

Next is a solution probably in better alignment with your current **assignment**. It also yields your desired output. Again this one requires **prior string-to-integer conversion** as described in the first section of the answer.

The principle here is to populate a list of every hit (hour with customer presence) in the form of single-row dataframes, then regroup all hits into one final dataframe (Without caring too much about code efifciency).

```py
df_list = []

for i in range(31):
    for j in range(24):
        # view dataframe subset meeting condition
        df_ij = df.loc[(df['REGIS_DAY']==i+1) & (df['REGIS_HOUR']==j)]
        # its number of rows
        s_ij = len(df_ij)
        # assign it to table
        if s_ij>0:
            df_list.append(pd.DataFrame({'REGIS_DAY'  : [i],
                                         'REGIS_HOUR' : [j],
                                         'sum'        : [s_ij]}))
# Concatenate the list of dataframes into a single table.
pd.concat(df_list, axis=0)

   REGIS_DAY  REGIS_HOUR  sum
0          2           3    3
0          6          16    2
0         15           4    1
0         23           3    1
0         28          13    4
```

For further reading I recommend [Creating an empty Pandas DataFrame, and then filling it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13784192/12846804)

*For good practices, just avoid naming a column like a pandas function. Here namely `sum` because the syntax `df.sum` might then not provide what you expect. Naming the column 'Sum' is enough to remove ambiguity.*

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need:

```
df = (df
      .groupby(['REGIS_DAY', 'REGIS_HOUR'])
      .size()
      .reset_index()
      .rename(columns={0:'sum'}))

print(df)
```

Output:

```
   REGIS_DAY    REGIS_HOUR  sum
0   3                3      3
1   7               16      2
2   16               4      1
3   24               3      1
4   29              13      4
```

If you still want to use a loop, use:

```
REGIS_DAY = []
REGIS_HOUR = []
sum = []
for i in range(31):
    for j in range(24):
        REGIS_DAY.append(i)
        REGIS_HOUR.append(j)
        sum.append(len(df[(df['REGIS_DAY'] == i) & (df['REGIS_HOUR'] == j)]))
        
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'REGIS_DAY': REGIS_DAY,
                       'REGIS_HOUR': REGIS_HOUR,
                       'sum': sum})
```

Comment: how to do with loop ?  for i in range(31):
    for j in range(24):

Comment: Hi. Reassigning the groupby as df implies overwriting and losing data. What if OP needs their other data later?

Comment: @Meeras i update my answer for loop solution

Comment: df = (df
      .groupby(['REGIS_DAY', 'REGIS_HOUR'])
      .size()
      .reset_index()
      .rename(columns={0:'sum'}))
This gives the correct/expected result. But with loop, all sum column is 0

Comment: My assignment needs to submit the solution with a loop. I am from a different language background and learning Python for data analysis as a part of my career switch. Handling data as a whole instead of reading line by line is confusing for me.  Thanks for you time and quick reply